Creating raster layer of distance to vector layer's features (e.g. rivers, roads, lakes) in QGIS
I would like to create a raster layer that shows a continuous distance from a (polyline or polygon) vector layer's features such as rivers, roads, or lakes in QGIS.
I have tried making this layer with various buffer tools, but those create a series of discrete rings rather than something that is continuous. I think at least the first step might be to rasterize the vector layer, but I don't know the tool to use after that
I have seen someone else do this in the past and it looked like this:

Here's a sample of what my stream layer looks like:



Rasterize your line layer. A fixed value to burn=1
Proximity (raster distance), target_pixels = 1, distance_units=Georeferenced coordinates



This. Simple, two steps, gets you exactly what you want.

Both are throwing errors. When I burn 1 it makes a scale from 1 to 1

Set Output raster size units to Georeferenced units and a pixel height and width. I use 5 m

The proximity tool is still not giving me the output I'm looking for

Would urge you to explore Atlas.co (free). You can simply select your vector data as input to the distance raster operation. Easy to export the distance raster and bring it back to QGIS.

